# Where can I ask questions about Google Cloud Platform, in regards to word definitions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to find the right place to post the question below:

---

**Title**

What are the definitions for Owner, Administrator, Editor, Creator, and Viewer in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

**Body**

What would be the definitions of Owner, Administrator, Editor, Creator, and Viewer in GCP?

The [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) is confusing because it doesn't provide a clear definition of each.

Let's assume we are writing a Dictionary about words used in GCP. What would be the definition for each of them?

For example:

- Administrator: noun

  - A person who grant roles to other users.
  - A person who can create, edit, and change access.

While I'm aware that their "permissions" change depending of the level (org, folder, org), the resources (BigQuery), and which department in Google decide to call each role (predefined and custom roles), it doesn't help me to provide a general explanation of each role.

I already read Google documentation, purchased a book for the GCP ACE Certification, and even reached a Google representative via their Support channel, but I can't get a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

General questions about the words choosen by technical writers in a document might be asked in

- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com)
  Relate tags: [technical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical), [tech-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-writing), [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Questions about writing and writing resources might be asked in

- [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com) Related tags: [dictionary](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing)

If you want to make a very specific question, you might have to ask directly to the writer or to a Google Developer Relationship agent, i.e. if they have a style guide and company specific writing resources for technical writers and if they are shared publicly.

P.S You might find helpful to read [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web), [Semantics of Business Vocabulary and Business Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_of_Business_Vocabulary_and_Business_Rules). On this articles you could learn some concepts and find resources that might help you to refine your search.

---

The words Owner, Administrator, Editor, Creator, and Viewer in the referred article are values assigned to the property Title used for the correponding role.

> **Basic roles**
>
> Basic roles are highly permissive roles that existed prior to the introduction of IAM. You can use basic roles to grant principals broad access to Google Cloud resources.
>
> | Name | Title | Permissions |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | roles/viewer | Viewer | Permissions for read-only actions that do not affect state, such as viewing (but not modifying) existing resources or data. |

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about GCP.

That being said, Stack Overflow has a [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) tag, which in turn has several sub tags.

**Before posting your question there**, you should thoroughly read the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-platform/info) to see if your question would be a good fit.

I also recommend that you type "documentation" into the search field for that tag and [read several existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-platform%5Ddocumentation) to see if others have asked questions that are analogous to yours.

Lastly, perform your own search on the tag using keywords from your question.

Comment: In Stack Overflow a question about documentation and terms meaning might be on topic if it is direclty related to a programming problem (writing code / fixing a bug and alike). Questions about writing a dictionary are off-topic.